# Vue js I need to access text-area value inside method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to access text area typed value inside method and I tried different ways but I only get empty string.

v-model = message

Code

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-form>
      <v-text-field v-model="name" label="Name"></v-text-field>

      <v-textarea label="Message" v-model="message"></v-textarea>

      <v-btn class="primary" type="submit" @click="myMethod">Save</v-btn>
    </v-form>
    
    {{print1}}
    {{print2}}

    
  </v-container>
</template>



<script>
export default {
  name: "Notifications",
  data() {
    return {
     
      message: "",
      
      print1:"",
      
      print2:"",
      
      testval: ""
     
    };
  },
  
  mounted() {
    this.testval = this.message;
  },
  
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
     
     this.print1=this.message;
     
     this.print2=this.testval;
     
     
    }
  },
  created() {
    
    this.myMethod();
  }
};
</script>
```

Example :

> Typed Value on textbox : Hello, How are you
>
> Expected Result on {{print1}} / {{print2}} = Hello, How are you
>
> Actual Result :

Comment: USE this.print1 and this.print2 in myMethod rather than print1 and print2

Comment: I tried that way as well but couldn't access text area value

Comment: you have to create the computed property to write data in print1 and print 2.
created method execute only one time when component is created. 
if you are changing value then it is going to change in v-model variable but not in print1 or print2.

computed: {
   print1: {
      return this.message} ,
}}

Comment: Why using created/mounted and other attributes just for one input property? You need simply this.message

Comment: No this is just to simplification purpose. I need access text area typed value for my big project. but I'm stuck in this point. what I'm going to do when I get typed value then I will extract placeholders from that message using regex. in order to do those I need to access typed value on text area

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: No there is no any error

Comment: Just try removing all unnecessary parts,like mounted/created hooks and print1,print2 and testval. You need this.message, so try console.log(this.message) in myMethod()

Comment: Use a computed property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is : Computed property

```
computed: {
    msg() {
      return this.message;
    }
}
```